# How to the compiler translate while(foo)?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

If I omit the operators from statement, something like this:  `while(foo)` will the compiler turn it in `while(foo != NULL || *foo != '\0' || foo != 0)` or `while(!foo)` or something like this?

how to it is really done?

Comment: Are you asking about assembly code generation or about semantics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`while (condition)` just checks for `condition` being non-zero.

Therefore these two are equivalent:

```
while (foo)
while (foo != 0)
```

Comment: But is there some difference in assembly code generation? I say, one is more faster than the other? and what do you uses in your C applications, the first or second code?

Comment: @Jack: They will (or they should) generate identical machine code.  It's a personal preference which to go for; I always use `while (foo != 0)` to be explicit, unless it's clear that the variable represents a Boolean condition, e.g. `while (isSunny)`.

Answer (score 1):

NULL, '\0' and 0 are functionally the same, only they're used for different types.

So if `foo` is, for instance, an int, `while (foo)` means `while (foo!=0)`

If foo is a pointer, `while (foo)` means `while (foo!=NULL)`

Etc. The compiler never checks the value that foo points to, though.